# azure function in java configure using function.json

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to create an Azure Function written in Java and configured using a function.json file (rather than using annotations).

To get started I followed the MS [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven) (which works ok).

Next, I tried to modify the class to remove the Function annotations and add a function.json as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java) in the section "The same function written without annotations".

The class source code is now:

```
public class Function {

    public static String hello(String req, ExecutionContext context) {
        return String.format("Hi, %s!", req);
    }

}
```

My function.json file is

```
{
    "scriptFile": "ServiceBusQueueMsgToLogWriter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
    "entryPoint": "com.oneadvanced.adv365.mgdsvc.azure.func.test1.Function.hello",
    "bindings": [
    {
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "name": "req",
        "direction": "in",
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "methods": [ "post" ]
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "name": "$return",
        "direction": "out"
    }
    ]
}
```

The output of running the command:

```
mvn clean package
```

Includes the output:

```
AI: INFO 12-10-2017 21:50, 1: Configuration file has been successfully found as resource
AI: INFO 12-10-2017 21:51, 1: Configuration file has been successfully found as resource
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 1 of 6: Searching for Azure Function entry points
[INFO] Reflections took 33 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values
[INFO] 0 Azure Function entry point(s) found.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 2 of 6: Generating Azure Function configurations
[INFO] No Azure Functions found. Skip configuration generation.
```

This makes me wonder if the function.json file isn't in the right place...

Does anyone know where the correct place to put the function.json file for an Azure Function written in Java?

I've tried:

- in the root of the project
- in src/main/resources (which I think would be the standard place for this kind of thing in a typical Java/Maven project)
- in the same folder as the Java source file

Same outcome in every case :(

I'd be grateful for any pointers on what I should be doing.

Thanks, Andy

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

> The code for all of the functions in a given function app lives in a
>   root folder that contains a host configuration file and one or more
>   subfolders, each of which contain the code for a separate function.

***Example Structure***:

```
wwwroot
 | - host.json
 | - mynodefunction
 | | - function.json
 | | - index.js
 | | - node_modules
 | | | - ... packages ...
 | | - package.json
 | - mycsharpfunction
 | | - function.json
 | | - run.csx
```

You could find the description above from [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#folder-structure).

However,I notice that your `function.json` file doesn't set `disabled` property.
Set the `disabled` property to `false` to enable the function which is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#function-code).

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "jaygong/test",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

---

***Update Answer:***

I tried to create my own azure function with the steps you provided by configuring `function.json` and I reproduced your issue!

***My function code:***

```
package cn.gjj;

public class Function {
    public static String hello(String in) {
        return in;
    }
}
```

***My function test code:***

```
package cn.gjj;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

/**
 * Unit test for Function class.
 */
public class FunctionTest {
    /**
     * Unit test for hello method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testHello() throws Exception {
        final Function function = new Function();

        final String ret = function.hello("function");

        assertEquals("function", ret);
    }
}
```

***My function.json file:***

```
{
  "scriptFile": "JayGongTestAzureFunction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint": "cn.gjj.Function.echo",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "name": "req",
      "direction": "in",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "methods": [ "post" ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the command  `mvn clean package`, the log shows as same as you.

```
AI: INFO 17-10-2017 14:07, 1: Configuration file has been successfully found as resource
AI: INFO 17-10-2017 14:07, 1: Configuration file has been successfully found as resource
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 1 of 6: Searching for Azure Function entry points
[INFO] Reflections took 31 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values
[INFO] 0 Azure Function entry point(s) found.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 2 of 6: Generating Azure Function configurations
[INFO] No Azure Functions found. Skip configuration generation.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 3 of 6: Validating generated configurations
[INFO] No configurations found. Skip validation.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 4 of 6: Saving empty host.json
[INFO] Successfully saved to E:\TestAzureFunction\JayGongTestAzureFunction\target\azure-functions\jaygongtestazurefunction-20171017132623892\host.json
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 5 of 6: Saving configurations to function.json
[INFO] No configurations found. Skip save.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 6 of 6: Copying JARs to staging directory E:\TestAzureFunction\JayGongTestAzureFunction\target\azure-functions\jaygongtestazurefunction-20171017132623892
```

After careful comparison of `function.json` configuration way and `annotations` way, I found directories of `Project/target/azure-functions/functionName/` folder are different.

***`annotations` way:***

[image]

***`function.json` configuration way:***

[image]

Note that if the `function.json` file is not found after `mvn compile`,please add the key line below in your `pom.xml` file.

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
       <includes>
          <include>host.json</include>
          <include>local.settings.json</include>
          **<include>function.json</include>**
       </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

***Solution：***

Create a job folder and move your `function.json` file into it.Then it works for me.

[image]

Please give it a try.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've added the disabled false line and it hasn't helped. I'd seen the example dir structure you've linked to - however the file structure in my project was created by the MS Maven archetype (and it worked with the annotations in place) so I'm assuming that the basic layout is correct.

Comment: I just tried running mvn -X clean package to get some debug info... I got [INFO] Step 1 of 6: Searching for Azure Function entry points
[DEBUG] going to scan these urls:
file:/Users/andyredhead/Documents/tmp/azure-function-java/ServiceBusQueueMsgToLogWriter/target/classes/   it seems that the maven plugin is looking at a copy of the compiled class directory structure, which doesnt include the function.json file.

Comment: @user2926169 Hi,please refer to my update answer.Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking further into this (and apologies for not responding sooner, I've been completely maxed for the last week or so). I'm still not clear about the job folder (sorry) - is the path shown in the screenshot in your solution section complete (or is a bit truncated on the right)? Thanks.

Comment: @user2926169  Ah,it's actually complete path.Just imitate annotations way to build a job folder and put your custom function.json file into it.

Comment: Just had another look... My function java now looks almost exactly the same as yours (I've taken off the ExecutionContext). I've set up maven to copy over a "hello" folder with the function.json in there - it still doesn't work. I note that the file created using annotations uses ../scriptname (I've tried with and without, it makes no difference). I note that your entry point is cn.gjj.Function.echo while your java fuction is named hello. Is this config working for you?